# React native android integration with existing app

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, react-native

I've followed the steps here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html

And I can get it to start an Activity that shows the loading spinner when in debug mode, however once it loads the `index.android.bundle` from the server it crashes with:

`ReactNativeJS: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'remoteModules.forEach')
ReactNativeJS: 'Failed to print error: ', 'Requiring module "58", which threw an exception.'`

I've tried it with 0.36 and 0.34.1.

Comment: did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: Add below snippet to you build.gradle under root folder 

```maven {
            url "$rootDir/node_modules/react-native/android"
 }```

Comment: I ended up just generating a new React Native android project, and working around that implementation to create the Activity.